# How to dehydrate chili at home?

Tags: chili-peppers, dehydrating, drying

Chilies have different temperatures for dehydration. Does anyone knows what temperature to use for Tabasco and Habanero? And the duration of the process?

Comment: Do you own a dehydrator? or are you using an oven?

Comment: @Batman i bought a dehydrator but I usualy use an oven.

Comment: If you want to be fancy, you can make a Chilli Ristra (the string of dried chilies).  I've heard that jalapeños and other thicker fleshed ones require more care (or they rot), but if you're not in a humid area, it could save a lot of effort and oven time.  You'll find instructions online.

Comment: @Joe thanks!!! Thats a good Idea!!! In wich Case i use the chili ristra? In fine dining?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the type of dining ... it's fancy in that it's decorative and looks impressive if you give it as gifts.  It's just a string of dried chilies that you can hang up in your kitchen (although, away from the stove or sink, so they don't re-absorb moisture).

Comment: Just remember that drying chilis in your house may stink it up something fierce. The fumes can make your eyes water, so do it at a time you can ventilate. Better yet, run the dehydrator in a garden shed or garage if you have one.

Comment: When i dry them in the oven (160° celsius) they liberate that gas. Even i lower temperatures they stink as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alton Brown teaches in an episode of Good Eats ['heat' is not the key to dehydration, but rather air flow](http://www.foodnetwork.com/videos/the-jerky-0107272) (you can skip to about 12:00 in). What you need is the "Blow Hard 3000" (A Box fan and a stack of air filters, the cheap ones are fine). He recommended (and I have tried and was successful with a variety of meats & herbs, including pablano peppers) taking a stack (4-5) Heat and Air filters. For peppers (and many other applications) fast moving dry COOL air is better than heat.